# Azure SQL and EF 6.1 won't return columns from stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I've looked at this answer which appears similar but neither solution helps. [EF Function Import does not recognise columns returned by StoredProc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561323/ef-function-import-does-not-recognise-columns-returned-by-storedproc)

There's no error but in the entity context, function imports when I edit the function to verify if the columns are correct it states "The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns" when I click the "Get Column Information" button.

The difference I believe is that this is azure and it's restrictive of the sql it allows. The sproc looks like this. Previously I had a union all with another result set but in effort to simplify it I split it out into two sprocs

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pipeline_List_By_Geography]
(
@Latitude float,
@Longitude float,
@intRadiusKm int = 5
)
As

DECLARE @SearchPoint as geography
SET @SearchPoint = geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326)

SELECT [ID] as "Id", [LegalName] AS "OfficeName", [Address], [City]
, [PostalCode], [CountryCode], [Brand], [Latitude], [Longitude], [SRID], 
([Point].STDistance(@SearchPoint)/1000) AS "distance",
[ProjectType], 'Pipeline' As "Source"
FROM TABLEA
WHERE [Point].STDistance(@SearchPoint) <= (@intRadiusKm * 1000)

GO
```

So, this returns a result set so I know the sproc works...it's some funky voodoo with the way EF and azure interact :-/

```
EXEC [dbo].[Pipeline_List_By_Geography] 32.783531, -96.796915, 50
```

Comment: Yes, sorry @usr, updated above. I think the spatial data functions is throwing things off. I have other sprocs that work just fine in the same context.