# Entity framework for execute string stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework

New to `EF`... using `6.0`. I've have a `Stored Proc` which has the dynamic build `select` query inside a string variable that outputs using `Execute(@StringQuery)`. This select has around 20 columns.

After adding this SP in EF, the return type is `INT` (not sure why). But I think I've to add all the columns manually in `Complex types in EDMX`. Wanted to know whether there is any better way to handle this as the columns are in huge number.

Please suggest.

Procedure Text:

```
DECLARE @StringQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @StringQuery = 'SELECT AROUND 20 COLUMNS WITH LOT OF CONDITIONS ADDED'

EXECUTE(@StringQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your model
2. Go to `View->Other Windows->Entity Data Model Browser`
3. In browser expand your `Model->Function Imports` and double click on `Stored Proc`
4. In `Returns a Collections off` choose Complex and press `Get Column Information`
5. Click `Create New Complex Type`
6. OK, Save

Comment: When I do that, I get message saying 'The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns' and OK button is disabled.

Comment: Can you paste you Procedure text?

Comment: I've added a sample of procedure how it looks like

Comment: Do you have logic in Storec proc which builds dynamic query?
Try at top of your procedyre `SET FMTONLY OFF`

Comment: Also read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128747/ef4-the-selected-stored-procedure-returns-no-columns