# The selected Stored Procedure returns No Columns using My SQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I am getting error 'The selected Stored Procedure returns No Columns' in Entity framework.

I have created the following Procedure in MySQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getCustomersByName`(
    p_Name varchar(50)
)
BEGIN

SELECT id,name,categoryid
FROM Customers  ;

END
```

Now i am using ADD Import Function to Import this procedure. then i am getting error. 
please provide me the solution of this problem.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128747/ef4-the-selected-stored-procedure-returns-no-columns

Comment: I am using MySQL Provider and when i click on Get Column Information Button to create complex type then i am getting error.