# The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2014

I've searched in the internet and found similar posts about it. However, no solution worked for me.

I'm facing an issue with one of my stored procedures. When adding it to my project in Visual Studio I get the following message:

> The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns.

Earlier I could solve the problem by adding `SET FMTONLY OFF` in my procedure (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128747/ef4-the-selected-stored-procedure-returns-no-columns)). Now this doesn't change anything; it still returns no columns according to EF.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spImportData]
    @someParameter
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Some insertion
    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable ([SomeField])
    SELECT @someParameter

    SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS BIGINT) AS ImportId
END
```

Same result when using a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (ImportId BIGINT)
INSERT INTO #temp (ImportId)
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS BIGINT)
SELECT ImportId FROM #temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Still no columns with a table variable:

```
DECLARE @importId BIGINT = SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS BIGINT)
SELECT @importId
```

When executing the procedure directly in SQL Server, I'm getting the desired value.

What am I missing? I thought `SET FMTONLY OFF` would do the trick but in this case nothing changes and my procedure still "returns no columns".

---

**Edit 1**

I tried what @NEER suggested in his comment. I changed the `SELECT` to `SELECT 1 AS ImportId`. But I'm still getting the same message.

Comment: Change `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS BIGINT) AS ImportId` to `SELECT 1 AS ImportId` then Update your entity.

Comment: @NEER I tried it but EF still doesn't recognize any columns.

Comment: Can you try this too? `SELECT 1 AS Foo FROM OneOfYourTable`

Comment: @NEER That doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue. I've added `SET FMTONLY OFF` on top of the inner block of my stored procedure *and* above the declaration because one of them alone didn't work. Neither did both of them together... So I removed the one inside the block and tried it again what surprisingly worked as expected.

My stored procedure now looks like this:

```
SET FMTONLY OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spImportData]
    @someParameter
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET FMTONLY OFF; -> I removed this line

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Some insertion
    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable ([SomeField])
    SELECT @someParameter

    SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS BIGINT) AS ImportId
END
```