# TableAdapter Configuration Wizard doesn't like temp tables in SP

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I'm using in a dataset to generate a report in ReportViewer.

This SP uses temporary tables to store intermediate values, so that these can be used in a calculation at the end of the SP.

The temp tables are all dropped cleanly at the end of the SP.

I can execute the SP in SSMS with no issues and it returns the data that I expect.

However, when use the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard to update my xsd in VS2012, it gives me the error `Invalid object name '#Held'` (where #Held is the name of one of the temp tables).

What's going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my typed dataset not like temporary tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921864/why-does-my-typed-dataset-not-like-temporary-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some known issues with #temp tables and table adapters.

Some people have got around it by explicitly selecting column names, eg:

`SELECT column1, column2, ... from #temptable` rather than `SELECT *` (if you are doing that)

You could also try using a `table` variable rather than a temp table.

Answer (score 28):

The answer stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921864/why-does-my-typed-dataset-not-like-temporary-tables) works perfectly, for reasons unknown.

Just place the below code after the stored procedure after the AS part of the SP.

```
IF 1=0 BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF
END
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. FMTONLY returns only metadata to the client. Can be used to test the format of the response without actually running the query.

Comment: You are my hero right now Bat. I've been banging my head against the wall for the past 2 hours trying to figure out why temp tables in an SP cause the TableAdapter Config Wizard to fail.

Comment: years later you saved someone's day today, know that. :)